# Jobs remain executing after Rundeck crashes/restarts

Tags: rundeck

Details:

- App Version: Rundeck Community - v4.2.1 (though the issue below has
  been around for some time)
- Database: Postgresql 9.6

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this?

In the event of a rundeck crash or server crash jobs which were executing remain in a running state. Navigating to the execution shows the following message:

*"Workflow State and Log Output is not available."*

This causes issues since a running execution will block subsequent executions and are not alerted on etc.

Is there a config setting that can be used to force any jobs in a RUNNING state to fail in the event of a rundeck service crash/restart?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the way is to use [Missed Job Fires](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/schedules/missedjobfires.html#missed-job-fires-enterprise-only) feature with [Job Resume](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/execution-lifecycle/job-resume.html#job-resume-plugin-enterprise) (both features only available on PagerDuty Process Automation On Prem, formerly "Rundeck Enterprise") to resume missed jobs/steps after a Rundeck server failure.